# get max value depending on condition

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group, amazon-athena

I have to compare total _revenue with target and multiplied with respective percent column. So once 750 is greater than 700 then it should multiply with 0.02 and ignore 500 and 400.
and if total_revenue is 470 then multiplied by 1% and ignores other.

sample data is like this

```
branch_id    total_revenue  target    percent   
2356             750         500       1.5%
2356             750         700       2%
2356             750         450       1%
2458             750         500       1.5%
2458             750         700       2%
2458             750         450       1%
```

desired output

```
    branch_id    total_revenue  target    percent  test percent
    2356             750         700      2%          15
    2458             750         700      2%          15
```

I am trying

```
 with revenue_cal(select a+b as  total_revenue from dummy table)
 ,percent_cal as (
  select a, b, .....
, (case when (select total_revenue from revenue_cal) > (target) 
 then((percent/100)*total_revenue)
        else 0 end)  as test_percent)
```

I can't use max function here because I have eighty columns and I don't want to group by on them, I can just group by on id. It work fine  if total revenue is  less than  smallest number but then other values repeat. I don't want repetition.

```
branch_id    total_revenue  target    percent  target percent 
2356             450         500       1.5%        00
2356             450         700       2%          00
2356             450         450       1%          4.5  
2458             450         500       1.5%        00
2458             450         700       2%          00
2458             450         450       1%          4.5
```

it should be

```
branch_id    total_revenue  target    percent  target percent 
2356             450         450       1%          4.5 
2458             450         450       1%          4.5
```

How can I get desired output?

Comment: You have not explained the rule how 6 rows turn into one.

Comment: What is the difference between first data sample and second except for the extra column?

Comment: there should be only one row for each branch_id for which total_revenue is relevant. so if total revenue is 750 only 700 with 2 % should be available

Comment: _"so if total revenue is 750 only 700 with 2 % should be available"_ - and why is that? What is the rule? I can generate a lot of rules which will allow to deduce 700 from 750.

Comment: sorry my bad. I have updated it. there are two scenarios for two different total_revenue.it could be max or it could be some different value.

Comment: Can you please write rule for row selection in words? Something like "maximum value" or "maximum value which is equal or less then revenue".

Comment: "maximum value which is greater then target

Comment: _"maximum value which is greater then target "_ - greater then what target? Maximum what? You example shows only rows with different targets while `total_revenue` seems to be constant.

Comment: Are you trying to get the rows that have the smallest target value that is greatest or equal to total_revenue? i.e. 750 is the smallest value >= 700 in the first sample and 450 is the smallest value >= 450 in the second sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *suppose* that, for each branch, you want the row whose total is equal to the target, or with the "closest" greater total.

If so, you can use `row_number` like so:

```
select
from (
    select t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by branch_id order by total_revenue - target) rn
    where total_revenue >= target
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```